# Equivalent electrons, terms of atomic subshell

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy

Let's say I consider $p^2$ case. For non-equivalent electrons it gives six possible terms: $\{^1S, ^1P, ^1D, ^3S, ^3P, ^3D\}$.

When we consider equivalent electrons, Pauli principle, obviously excludes the triplet $\{^3D\}$. So my answer is $\{^1S, ^1P, ^3S, ^3P, ^1D\}$.

The right answer is $\{^1S, ^3P, ^1D\}$=(

What happened to $\{^1P, ^3S\}$? $\{^1P\}$ is the state with $m_{\ell1}=\pm1, m_{s1}=\pm1/2$ and $m_{\ell2}=0, m_{s2}=\mp1/2$, hence $L=1$ and $S=0$. $\{^3S\}$ state is $m_{\ell1}=\pm1, m_{s1}=\pm1/2$ and $m_{\ell2}=\mp1, m_{s2}=\pm1/2$, which gives $L=0$ and $S=1$.

Where am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Since there are 2$p$ electrons $\ell_1 = 1, \ell_2 = 1 \rightarrow L=0,1,2$ and $s_1=1/2, s_2=1/2 \rightarrow S=0,1$.

As you said, ignoring the Pauli principle results in $^3\text{D}, ^1\text{D},^3\text{P},^1\text{P},^3\text{S}$, and $^1\text{S}$ terms. The easiest way to impose the Pauli principle is to make a table as below where the first row and column contain the $m_\ell$ and $m_s$ values for electrons 1 and 2, respectively. Obviously, the diagonal terms correspond to electrons in the same state and are therefore not allowed. In addition, the symmetric states are the same so that the table contains 15 terms

```
           -1,-1/2    -1, 1/2   0,-1/2    0, 1/2   1,-1/2    1, 1/2
-1,-1/2       X
-1, 1/2    -2, 0         X
 0,-1/2    -1,-1      -1, 0       X
 0, 1/2    -1, 0      -1, 1     0, 0        X
 1,-1/2     0,-1       0, 0     1,-1      1, 0       X
 1, 1/2     0, 0       0, 1     1, 0      1, 1     2, 0        X
```

The maximum value of $M_L$ in the table corresponds to 2 and since the $^3\text{D}$ state is forbidden, this value of $M_L$ is associated with 5 states in the table: (2,0),(1,0),(0,0),(-1,0), and (-2,0). You can cross out all these terms in the table and replace them by the $^1\text{D}$ term symbol

```
           -1,-1/2    -1, 1/2   0,-1/2    0, 1/2   1,-1/2    1, 1/2
-1,-1/2       X
-1, 1/2     ^1D         X
 0,-1/2    -1,-1       ^1D       X
 0, 1/2    -1, 0      -1, 1     ^1D        X
 1,-1/2     0,-1       0, 0     1,-1      ^1D       X
 1, 1/2     0, 0       0, 1     1, 0      1, 1     ^1D        X
```

The next highest value of $M_L$ is 1 and $M_S=1$ and nine states are associated with this $^3P$ state (1,1), (1,0), (1,-1), (0,1), (0,0), (0,-1), (-1,1), (-1,0), and (-1,-1). Replacing the entries in the table by the corresponding symbol

```
           -1,-1/2    -1, 1/2   0,-1/2    0, 1/2   1,-1/2    1, 1/2
-1,-1/2       X
-1, 1/2     ^1D         X
 0,-1/2     ^3P        ^1D       X
 0, 1/2     ^3P        ^3P     ^1D        X
 1,-1/2     ^3P        ^3P     ^3P      ^1D       X
 1, 1/2     0, 0       ^3P     ^3P      ^3P     ^1D        X
```

The only state left is the $^1\text{S}$ state with $M_L=0$ and $M_S=0$.

Note that some configurations may occur a few times in a table (such as the (0,0) in this example), and there is no unique way of labeling, but you will always end up with the correct states if you follow this procedure.

Comment: I don't understand following from your post "The maximum value of ${M}_L$ in the table corresponds to 2 and since the $^{3}D$ state is forbidden, this value of ${M}_L$ is associated with 5 states in the table: (2,0),(1,0),(0,0),(-1,0), and (-2,0). You can cross out all these terms in the table and replace them by the $^{1}D$ term symbol". How can we just replace all states you mention with with $^{1}D$ ? For example, state (1,0) corresponds to L=1 and S=0, so that corresponds to the term $^{1}P$ right? How can we replace it with $^{1}D$ then?

Comment: This is because the $^1P$ configuration belongs to the $^1D$ configuration ($L=2$ can have 5 different projections).